# How to install RabbitMQ on centos 7 offline?

Tags: centos, rabbitmq, centos7

I'm using CentOS 7 and I want to install RabbitMQ on it, but before that I need erlang installed. As I'm new to CentOS, I don't know how to install it offline.
The OS has no internet connection and further it has no network connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can download the Zero dependency Erlang/OTP packages for CentOS 6 and 7, suitable for running RabbitMQ here:

- https://github.com/rabbitmq/erlang-rpm/releases
- (or) https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/erlang
- (or) https://bintray.com/rabbitmq/erlang